# Hidden documents of the website

Tags: web-services, security, hidden-files

I would like to ask you if it is possible such a thing...

I have the link of some pdf document (for example) www.website.com/folder/document.pdf

When I cut the previous link to www.website.com/folder/ it should show me the folder which must contain a document.pdf, but it doesn't show me anything.

Is it possible for me to see all the documents in that directory www.website.com/folder/ although this is hidden?

Comment: Not if you don't control the website.

Comment: It's called `DirectoryListing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web server can manage resources any way it sees fit, and *www.website.com/folder/* is not necessarily a directory on the web server's machine. It's part of the [Uniform Resource Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) *http://www.website.com/folder/document.pdf* and need not be a valid resource locator itself. For example, a web server could store all documents in a DB, and match the path to a particular table.

Even if your assumptions, that parts of a resource locator refer to directories on a web server were true, a web server can still (and usually does) deny clients to list directory entries.

If you don't control the web server, then your goal is not generally possible.